# <a> tag in css does not appear to be correct

Tags: html, css

This is my code for html/css:

```
<p>
  <img src="image.jpeg">
  <a href="#" style="position: absolute;margin-left: 3%;">Upgrade or 
  downgrade my plan</a>
</p>
```

and this is what appears:
[image]

However, I want it to appear like this:
[image]

How do i make it appear like the image above?

Comment: The text appears as you want, maybe there is another code that is interfering. http://jsfiddle.net/6x2vpu6b/

Answer (score 1):

The style of the tag `a` is overlapped by other styles.so change it using this code:

```
p a {
    border-bottom: none!important;
    text-decoration: underline!important;
    font-size:18px!important;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.link-ref {
    position: absolute; /*already existing style*/
    margin-left: 3%; /*already existing style*/
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #111;
}
</style>

<p>
  <img src="image.jpeg">
  <a href="#" class="link-ref">Upgrade or downgrade my plan</a>
</p>
```

adding !important and add comment for common elements may affect other elements in your page